# "TypeError: data.map is not a function" on accessing newsapi using nextjs/react

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to access newsapi using nextjs/react but "TypeError: data.map is not a function".

I have tried the following some solutions provided on stackoverflow but did not work for my case.

Here is my code:

```
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js'
import Link from 'next/link'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const Index = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Batman TV sources</h1>
    <ul>
      {props.sources.map(source => (
        <li key={source.id}>
          <Link as={`/p/${source.id}`} href={`/post?id=${source.id}`}>
            <a>{source.name}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </Layout>
)

Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/search/sources?q=batman')
  //const res = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
  //const res = await fetch ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us')
  const data = await res.json()

  //console.log(`source data fetched. Count: ${data.length}`)

  return {
    sources: data.map(entry => entry.source)
  }
}

export default Index
```

and here SHORTED api data looks like:
{"status":"ok","totalResults":38,"articles":[{"source":{"id":"fox-news","name":"Fox News"},"author":"Frank Miles","title":....}]}

I know this is an object but not an array and map() is not valid for object. But how can I get around this based on my code above?

The expected result should be new headlines be displayed but always got "TypeError: data.map is not a function". I tried the solutions suggested here but did not work. I am kind of new to this.

Comment: I fixed using "data.articles.map(entry => entry.source)".

Answer (score 4):

Since your data is an `Object` you can't use `map` on it as `Object` don't have `map` method, you're trying to map `source` property which is inside `articles` array

change this

```
data.map(entry => entry.source)
```

to this

```
data.articles.map(entry => entry.source)
```